# Passing named arrays to another bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I would like to pass multiple named arrays to another bash script as they are.
For example, given
outer.sh

```
echo "outer"
a=(1 2)
b=(3 4 5)
echo ${#a[@]}
echo ${#b[@]}
a=${a[@]} b=${b[@]} sh inner.sh
```

and inner.sh

```
echo "inner"
echo ${a[@]}
echo ${b[@]}
echo ${#a[@]}
echo ${#b[@]}
```

running the outer.sh gives

```
$ sh outer.sh
outer
2
3
inner
1 2
3 4 5
1
1
```

That is, even though values are preserved, but their lengths change, which means, they are not arrays anymore, but strings.

How do I pass multiple named arrays to another bash script as they are?

Comment: Through the environment, it simply can't be done without serializing and deserializing. Environment variables are NUL-delimited, and so are individual array elements, so the boundary between two elements in an array would become the boundary ending an environment variable if you tried to pass it literally.

Comment: ...that said, the serialization/deserialization necessary is very much akin to how you'd copy arrays' contents to/from a command-line argument vector, and we already have some Q&A entries describing how to do *that*.

Comment: BTW, `sh` doesn't support arrays at all. Maybe you wanted `bash inner.sh`?

Comment: (Not that using `.sh` extensions for bash scripts is great practice: Using a `.sh` extension implies that your code is POSIX sh compliant, which it isn't if it uses arrays; and also means that if you rewrite it to use a different interpreter,  you need to rename it and then modify every single caller unless you want the name to be misleading. If a script is meant to be executed rather than sourced, better to use no extension at all, and let its shebang be used to a select an interpreter).

Comment: Is writing `a_arr=($a)` in inner.sh deserializing that you commented?

Comment: Technically it's deserialization, but it's *extremely buggy* deserialization.

Comment: Be sure you test with array elements with spaces; array elements which contain glob characters (`a=('*')` is  a good test case, since it'll always expand); array elements containing literal newlines; etc. There are lots of corner cases that can mess things up if not handled correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches available, each with their own disadvantages.

---

#### The Easy Way: Run The Inner Script Inside A Subshell

This means *all* variables are inherited, including ones (like arrays!) that can't be passed through the environment.

```
a=(1 2)
b=(3 4 5)
(. inner)
```

Of course, it also means that shell settings (`IFS`, `set -e`, etc) are inherited too, so `inner.sh` needs to be written robustly to handle whatever setup it may happen to receive; and you can't rewrite it in a different / non-shell language later.

---

#### The Unsafe Way: Pass `eval`-able code (and trust your caller!)

Modify `inner.sh` to run `[[ $setup ]] && eval "$setup"`, and then invoke it as:

```
setup=$(declare -p a b) ./inner
```

Obviously, this is a severe security risk if you don't control the process environment.

---

#### The Hard Way: Deserialize into individual elements

Here, we pass each array as its name, its length, and then its original elements.

`inner` needs to be modified to copy items off its command-argument list back into the arrays, as in the following example:

```
while (( $# )); do               # iterating over our argument list:
  dest_name=$1; shift            # expect the variable name first
  dest_size=$1; shift            # then its size
  declare -g -a "$dest_name=( )" # initialize our received variable as empty
  declare -n dest="$dest_name"   # bash 4.3: make "dest" point to our target name
  while (( dest_size )) && (( $# )); do  # and then, for up to "size" arguments...
    dest+=( "$1" ); shift                # pop an argument off the list onto an array
    (( dest_size -= 1 ))                 # and decrease the count left in "size"
  done
  unset -n dest   # end that redirection created above
done
```

...and then expand into that format in `outer`:

```
./inner a "${#a[@]}" "${a[@]}" b "${#b[@]}" "${b[@]}"
```

Comment: "easy way" seems fairly robust, but i'm a bit of bash newb

Comment: It's good enough for most use cases, so long as your scripts are developed together and you know nobody will ever want to rewrite the inner one in, say, Python or Go. "The Hard Way" is the only approach that's fully language-agnostic (you can receive arrays passed that way in any language you might want to)... though one could also maybe use a language-agnostic serialization format like serializing to JSON with `jq` if that were an explicit goal.